# Using Custom Themes

Tags: themes, custom

Just getting starting with EE. I have a custom HTML5 theme I've been designing and would like to upload it to EE.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Any great free tutorials would be helpful as well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

EE doesn't really have themes per se. You'd need to manually build out your content types and templates using the EE templating language.

If you're looking on how to build for the first time, look no further than http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/books/detail/building-an-expressionengine-2-site-small-business/ or https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/expressionengine-tutorial/ - both excellent EE learning resources.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I've found some great free info & tutorials:
From DaBrook: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7D18703E2B770DA0
and from http://viminteractive.com/blog/a_newbies_guide_to_expressionengine_development/

Comment: Please edit your original question and add this follow up information, and then delete this answer. This isn't really an answer, and EE is front-end framework agnostic.